# Powershell loop to read into array from an imported CSV

Tags: powershell

I have a script that imports a CSV which I then read certain values into an array.

How can I use a loop to make this better?

```
$list = Import-Csv "c:\temp\list.csv"

$array_list = @()

foreach ($item in $list) {

$array_list += $item.position1

$array_list += $item.position2

$array_list += $item.position3

$array_list += $item.position4

$array_list += $item.position5

$array_list += $item.position6

$array_list += $item.position7

$array_list += $item.position8

$array_list += $item.position9

$array_list += $item.position10

}
```

Comment: So you literally just want to add every field into a flat array?

Comment: There are other fields but I want to add these 10 into an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways. Here is one:

```
$array_list = @()
foreach($row in (Get-Content c:\temp\List.csv | Select-Object -Skip 1)){
    $array_list += ($row.split(','))[0..9]
}
```

You might have to tweak it a little if there are spaces or quotes that you don't want.

If you want to do it based on the property name:

```
$contents = Import-CSV C:\temp\Test.csv
$propertyNames = gm -in $contents[0] | ?{$_.name -like '*position*'} | select -expand name
$array_list = @()
foreach($row in $contents){
    foreach($name in $propertyNames){
        $array_list += $row.$name
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it will add all the fields into the array. The CSV has other fields like name, surname, location, etc. I only want to use the fields specifically called "position" which range from position1 to position10 - hope that makes sense.

Comment: Just the first 10. Did you try it?

Comment: Perhaps you should try it.

Comment: Aaah, so it is not the literal first 10 fields? Is it only the fields named positionX?

Comment: Yes, correct it is not the first 10. But I used your code to specify the positions and it worked, so thanks for pointing me in the right direction. And there was a slight error in the code, $result should be $array_list.

Comment: I'd try to avoid `+=` which will rebuild $array_list each time `$array_list = foreach($row in (Get-Content c:\temp\List.csv | Select-Object -Skip 1)){ ($row.split(','))[0..9]}` same for your new variant.

Comment: Yeah, I was just keeping it true to the method used in the question. To be honest I pretty much always use ArrayLists anyway. :)

Comment: `ArrayLists` and `List[T]s`, make life much better

Comment: Guys is there a way to call a specific value from the variable containing the imported csv? Say $import contains the imported CSV, can I say $import[5]? Or something like that? Or do I have to use the name, as in $import.surname?

Comment: Well `$import[5]` would return the 6th object in the array. So all the properties on that object. `$import.surname` would return all of the surname values from all of the objects in the array (depending on your version of Powershell). If you want the surname of the 6th object then it would be `$import[5].surname`.

Answer (score 2):

***If* your intent is to simply extract a *subset* of the columns in the CSV**, you
can simply use `Select-Object`:

```
$array = Import-Csv "c:\temp\list.csv" | Select-Object -Property position*
```

Note the use of a *wildcard pattern* to select the properties to extract; matching columns are extracted in *input order*, so if the CSV contains columns `position0`, `position1`, ... `position10` in that order (possibly interspersed with differently named columns), then **the output collected in `$array` (which is of type `[object[]]`) contains *custom objects* with properties named for those columns - in order - containing the respective rows' column values**.

(Of course, you can explicitly enumerate the columns to extract by passing them as an *array* to `Select-Object -Property` (e.g., `Select-Object -Property position4, position 7`), and you can even mix literal column names with wildcard expressions in the argument array.)

---

***If* you actually meant to collect the `position*` column values in a *single, flat array across all input rows*** (PSv3+):

```
$array = Import-Csv "c:\temp\list.csv" | Select-Object -Property position* |
  ForEach-Object { $_.psobject.properties.value }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$fields = 'position1', 'position2', 'position3', 'position4', 
          'position5', 'position6', 'position7', 'position8', 
          'position9', 'position10'


$array = foreach ($line in Import-Csv "c:\temp\list.csv")
{
    $fields | foreach-object {
        $line.$_
    }
}
```